# php get form value from previous page after an ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

As the question stated, how do I retrieve the form values from the previous page.

Basically I'm creating a form wizard
1. enter the form inputs -> next step
2. confirmation and get all the values

I can use `$_GET` to get those values from the URL address, but for the form validation I'm using jquery ajax. Do I need to create a session variable for each text input value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Save the values in `$_SESSION` and retrieve them on the next page:

```
// On the first page....
session_start();
// Process your code...
$_SESSION['val1'] = $_POST['val1']; // don't forget your validation
$_SESSION['val2'] = $_POST['val2'];

// Display the next part of your form...

// On the second page
session_start();
// Retrieve your values
$val1 = $_SESSION['val1'];
$val2 = $_SESSION['val2'];

// Retrieve values from the second part of your form
something($_POST['val3']);
something($_POST['val4']);
```

Answer (score 2):

yes, you have to use session to preserve data between HTTP requests.

Answer (score 1):

Another way: you can create multi pages using js and displaying next one when validation for curr page is complete. There's lot of jQuery plugins to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can also store a serialized json object that contains all the form data inside a cookie.

Answer (score 0):

After validating the form you can send another ajax request. Your data will then be available in $_GET.